# Is it possible to run different php versions for different virtual hosts?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, content-management-system

On my server I run different versions of various CMS (: Joomla, Wordpress, Drupal) because of customizations that prevent to update them all to the latest version. 
For Drupal 7.x I would like to run php 5.3 while the other sites are fine with php 5.2. 
Is there any way to configure apache in such a way so that the virtual hosts that run the Drupal 7 are with php 5.3?

Comment: have you seen this? http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/

Comment: No. Looks like this is the answer. I will have to try it first though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Per VirtualHost Config 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 DocumentRoot /Apache22/htdocs/fcgi 
 ServerName fcgi.local 
 ErrorLog logs/fcgi.error.log 
 CustomLog logs/fcgi.access.log common 
 <Directory "/Apache22/htdocs/fcgi"> 
     SetEnv PHPRC "c:/php" 
     AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
     FcgidWrapper "C:/php/php-cgi.exe" .php 

     AllowOverride all 
     Order allow,deny 
     Allow from all 
     Satisfy any 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to unixify this but that's all right :)